# can かbe repeated [noun] か +　かと思うような?

Tags: particles, suffixes

Studying for the JLPT and this practice question shows me something novel that I don't think I've ever heard:

it's a sequence problem and the correct sequence the book tells me is:

彼女は　新人　ながら　ベテランか　かと思うような落ち着きぶりだった。

Something seems off about the repeated か to me. What is the repeated one doing?

Comment: I'm quite certain that this repeated `か` is grammatically incorrect. The textbook made a typo, or you got it wrong. If that is the case, this question [may be closed](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1185/how-should-we-handle-typo-questions-now-that-too-localized-is-gone).

Comment: @naruto What's wrong with it, grammatically speaking? I'm curious because I think I'v definitely seen things like "何かかと思う" or "どちらかかと思う" every so often. Then again, of course it could simply be people not paying attention to grammar online.

Comment: Native speaker here.  (1) I have absolutely no idea what that sentence even means with two か's in it.  Delete one of them and it makes perfect sense. (2) Despite Semaphore's claim, one cannot say a phrase like "何かかと思う" or "どちらかかと思う" all by itself.  One must say 「Aか何かかと思う」 or 「AかBのどちらかかと思う。」.  Notice the crucial difference between a regular noun like 「ベテラン」 and question words like なに and どちら.  Had the middle part of the sentence in question been 「ベテランか何かかと思うような」, it would have at least been a grammatical sentence.

Comment: Yes it can be grammatical if "AかBか" idiom is combined with "かと思う", so "ベテランか何かかと思う" is OK. (Google "何かかと思う" and see what comes before this) but "ベテランかかと思う" by itself sounds quite weird to me.

Comment: Okay I've voted to close my own question. It's relieving to hear the question was flawed. Seemed like gibberish to me but as a non-native speaker sometimes that's just my inabilitiy.